# All modules getting loaded in browser in-spite of very few imports

Tags: angular, rxjs, systemjs

I am getting started with a project on angular2 built in Visual Studio 2015 with Typescript.

The solution has a `node_modules` folder which contains all the frameworks for dependencies.

I have configured systemjs as below:

```
    System.config({
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        paths: {
            'angular2/*': 'node_modules/angular2/*',
            'rxjs/add/observable/*': 'node_modules/rxjs/add/observable/*.js',
            'rxjs/add/operator/*': 'node_modules/rxjs/add/operator/*.js',
            'rxjs/*': 'node_modules/rxjs/*.js'
        }
    });
    System.import('scripts/app.js');
```

I have created a single component with the following imports:

```
import {Component, View, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from 'angular2/common';
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {Http, Headers, HTTP_PROVIDERS, Response, XHRBackend} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/Rx';
```

The App works properly but viewing the network tab in the browser, It looks like all JS files (471 files) in the `node_modules` folder are being loaded by systemJs resulting into network usage of around 4.9 MB.

I would like to know how I can limit the file loading as per the imports.

I am currently using `angular2 alpha 53` with `rxjs@5.0.0-alpha.14` and `systemjs at 0.18.4.`

Thankyou!

Comment: you use dist to reducing the file size , Try using [grunt](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1096/using-grunt-gulp-bower-visual-studio-2013-2015) as task runner

Comment: You should remove `angular2/*` path, there's no need for it, and of course, you are importing the full Rx, you could refactor it to only import the operators you need.

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue.  Have you found an answer?

Comment: @tomSchreck , There is not much we can do, angular2 has loads internal dependencies by itself. mostly all modules are inter dependent as of now.